# Count of commits in azure devops git repo using Python

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am  trying to count no of commits in a repo in Azure devops using python. I am referring this https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api. Can anybody help me in how to count no of commits in azure devops using python.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for branch in git_repo_branch:
                pprint.pprint(branch.name)

            git_repo_commit=git_client.get_commits(repo.name,search_criteria=)

I am here so I am trying to use search criteria but how to use search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#all-commits), it will return the count.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=6.0
```

[image]

So the code in Python will be:

```
import requests
import base64
import json

pat = 'YOUR PAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}
response = requests.get(
    url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=6.0", headers=headers)

data = json.loads(response.content)
print(data['count'])
```

I also tried the method in Python [`get_commits`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/released/git/git_client_base.py#L324). But it will return the commit objects without count.

```
git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client()
commits = git_client.get_commits("repo_id", None)
```

Comment: I tried via rest api and i was able to get the commit count of a repository, could you please tell what "authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')" line of code is doing?

Comment: It's used to [authenticate with PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). A personal access token (PAT) is used as an alternate password to authenticate into Azure DevOps. You could use [OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) to instead.